# WSO2 AIPM import api_params.yaml not working

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I tried to export an API from DEV to PROD using CLI tool and have defied the production URL for prod environment in `api_params.yaml` but after importing I see in prod the same url as it is in dev which is wired because I have defined url for prod in `api_params.yaml`. I am using wso apim 2.6.0 with `import-expot2.5.0v1`

**The following are the console logs**

```
[2020-06-25 15:17:05,609]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-06-25 15:17:05,609+0530]
[2020-06-25 15:17:05,629]  INFO - AuthenticatorUtil admin user authenticated successfully
[2020-06-25 15:17:05,820]  INFO - AuthenticatorUtil admin is authorized to import and export APIs
[2020-06-25 15:17:05,851]  INFO - APIService Creation of folder is successful. Directory Name : testapi1-1.0
[2020-06-25 15:17:05,859]  INFO - APIService Creation of folder is successful. Directory Name : Meta-information
[2020-06-25 15:17:05,902]  INFO - APIService Creation of folder is successful. Directory Name : Sequences
[2020-06-25 15:17:05,905]  INFO - APIService Creation of folder is successful. Directory Name : in-sequence
[2020-06-25 15:17:05,908]  INFO - APIService Creation of folder is successful. Directory Name : Custom
[2020-06-25 15:17:08,434]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-06-25 15:17:08,434+0530]
[2020-06-25 15:17:09,658]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-06-25 15:17:09,658+0530]
[2020-06-25 15:22:05,928]  INFO - InboundDBSyncRequestEvent Running DB sync task.
```

Comment: Can you try importing with --update and see? apimcli import-api -f ./SwaggerPetstore -e prod --update -k

Comment: Also please verify you have did it correctly referring https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Building+CICD+Pipeline#BuildingCICDPipeline-Addingenvironment-specificparametersforAPIs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your [code/log is pretty unreadable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/) and it's unlikely that other people can read your output. Please read [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)